# Place box-shadow behind sibling in CSS

Tags: css, box-shadow

I would like a series of divs with no margin and both top and bottom box shadows such that the box shadows of each div do not overlap any other divs.  I've constructed a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehxsdjr8/8/) to show what I'm trying to achieve and what I have now.  This seems like something that `z-index` could be used for, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of your DIVs in one outer wrapper DIV.  Apply a box shadow to that, and to the hover state of each internal DIV.  Now each can be controlled independentaly.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">The box shadow from each div...</div>
  <div class="inner">...should go under each other div.</div>
  <div class="inner">The whole thing should look...</div>
  <div class="inner">...like one big div with a shadow...</div>
  <div class="inner">...unless you hover over one.</div>
</div>

div.outer {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #999;
  transition: padding .1s ease-in-out, width .1s ease-in-out, box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}

div.outer:hover {
  box-shadow: none;   
}

div.inner {
  padding: 20px;
  transition: padding .1s ease-in-out, width .1s ease-in-out, box-shadow .1s ease-in-out; 
}

div.inner:hover {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #666;
  margin-left: -20px
  width: 350px;
}
```

I've styled this such that the box shadow on the outer `DIV` disappears when you hover over it, so only the hovered inner`DIV` shows a shadow.  Adjust to taste :)

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ehxsdjr8/7/

Comment: Close, but not quite.  The sibling divs need to retain their box shadows and remain grouped.

Comment: Not sure I understand... so when not hovered, you want each div to show a box shadow, but when hovered, just the hovered div to have a shadow?

Comment: No, the divs should cover the box shadow of all siblings.  In that case, the unhovered divs retain their grouping and shadow while the hovered div pops out.

Comment: No, there are still overlapping box-shadows in that example.  No shadow should cover any part of any div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80308/discussion-between-astex-and-jeff-clarke).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehxsdjr8/9/)

```js
$( 'div' ).hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass( "hey" );
    $('div').not(this).addClass( "heyho" );
  }, function() {
      $(this).removeClass( "hey" );
    $('div').not(this).removeClass( "heyho" );
  }
);
```

```css
div {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #999;
    transition: padding .1s ease-in-out, width .1s ease-in-out, box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}
.hey{
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #666;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 350px;
}
.heyho {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>The box shadow from each div...</div>
<div>...should go under each other div.</div>
<div>The whole thing should look...</div>
<div>...like one big div with a shadow...</div>
<div>...unless you hover over one.</div>
```

Comment: No.  The goal is to have no box shadows overlapping any div.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ehxsdjr8/13

The trick here is to add multiple shadows to each div and turn them on/off as needed.  In this case, add the top shadow for the first element and the first element after a hover only and modify the existing shadow to not go above the element.

```
div {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #999;
    transition:
        padding .1s ease-in-out,
        width .1s ease-in-out,
        box-shadow .1s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #666;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 350px;
}
div:hover + div {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #999, 0px -3px 3px #999;
}
div:first-of-type {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #999, 0px -3px 3px #999;
}
div:first-of-type:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #666;
}
```

It'll take a lot of playing around to get this to look right.

Comment: Instead of adding margin to the hovered DIV, nest each DIV inside another.  The hover is applied to the outer DIV, and on hover, add padding instead of margin.  That way the mouse will continue to be over the item as it transitions.  The layered shadow effect is applied to the inner DIVs. The result is a smoother version of the above solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ehxsdjr8/19/